# How to trace a user who buys on eshop via google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, shopify-api

I need to make reports via GA API (v4) of some eshop. The owner of this eshop wants to trace info somehow, when someone buys something.

So he wants to know, if somebody buys something on his eshop, how many times before the user have visited the eshop before and where he walked through (which pages). The e-shop has Google analytics and Shopify features, from which I can potentialy obtain data and bound them together.

Is it something like that possible with API? I wanted to create User-ID, but I cant get it as dimension. So my idea was create some custom dimension with User-ID value (same as userId), but I dont know, if it is not forbidden, because it is the fake exactly.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Yes its possible but i recommend him creating the report he wants on the website first then you can use that to build your api request.    Ask him to show you the data he wants to see then go from there.   Random give me this will be to hard for you because you dont know their data.

Comment: Ok, I will let him know. But problem is, how can I obtain such data, when I cant get info of userId? I still can't imagine how to combine in api dimensions and metrics to compile such a report. Thanks. :)

Comment: Unless they have a custom dimension for their internal user ids you cant.  Your not supposed to be doing personal identifiable analytics with google analytics really.    The website uses the api.  If they can make it work on the website you can make the same request via the api.   You are just making them prove that it will work before you try coding something.   If they cant get the back then neither can you.